# Перестал работать метод map

Tags: xcode, swift

Ранее, до обновления Swift до 4.2 работал метод как обычно

```
_ = array.map {names in
                let cen = names.price}
```

array это массив пользовательского класса

```
class AddClass: Decodable {



var name500: String
var date500: String
var images: [Image]
var ima: String
var price: [Price]
var prices: String
var sales: String
var display_price: String

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name500 = "name"
    case date500 = "release_date"
    case images = "images"
    case price = "skus"
    case ima
    case prices
    case sales
    case default_sku
}

enum RatingsCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case display_price = "display_price"
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .name500)
    date500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .date500)
    images = try conteiner.decode([Image].self, forKey: .images)
    price = try conteiner.decode([Price].self, forKey: .price)
    ima = ""
    prices = ""
    sales = ""


    let ratingsContainer = try conteiner.nestedContainer(keyedBy: RatingsCodingKeys.self, forKey: .default_sku)
    self.display_price = try ratingsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .display_price)
}
}
```

**Вопрос, как теперь обратиться к свойствам класса в массиве?**

Прочитал, что якобы можно таким способом обращаться:

```
let person = Person()
print(person.name)
print(person.city)
print(person.favoriteIceCream)
```

Но при попытке обращения

```
let array = AddClass()
```

просит инициализировать так

```
let array = AddClass(from: <#Decoder#>)
```

и что вписать вместо **<#Decoder#>** я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Все, понял, просто теперь нужно писать не так

```
_ = array.map {names in
            let cen = names.price}
```

а так

```
_ = array.map {names in
names.map {p in
            let cen = p.price}}
```